# How to set website theme to all webpages using a drop down list?

Tags: c#, themes

I am trying to use a drop down list on my homepage to select and set the theme for all webpages. It sets it for the homepage but when I go to any other page it has no theme. This is my code for my homepage:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string selectedTheme = Page.Theme;
            HttpCookie userSelectedTheme =
            Request.Cookies.Get("UserSelectedTheme");

            if (userSelectedTheme != null)
            {
                selectedTheme = userSelectedTheme.Value;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTheme) &&
            ddlSetTheme.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme) != null)
            {
                ddlSetTheme.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme).Selected =
                true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ddlSetTheme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie userSelectedTheme = new
        HttpCookie("UserSelectedTheme");
        userSelectedTheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6);
        userSelectedTheme.Value = ddlSetTheme.SelectedValue;
        Response.Cookies.Add(userSelectedTheme);
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
    }

    private void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie setTheme = Request.Cookies.Get("UserSelectedTheme");
        if (setTheme != null)
        {
            Page.Theme = setTheme.Value;
        }
    }
```

I am thinking that the code I have is only sufficient to apply the theme to one page, so how do I apply it to all pages?

Comment: Why don't you use a Master Page and set the theme for that? It will auto reflect for the pages

Answer (score 0):

By default, your HttpCookie's scope is the page you're on.

If you want it to be the entire domain, you need to set the Path to be the entire site, probably like this:

```
userSelectedTheme.Path = "/";
```

More info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: 1) Check the cookie definition in your browser and determine the scope. The scope needs to be your entire domain/website for the cookie to available site-wide. 2) In addition do that, try outputting the cookie value on other pages and confirm it's being retrieved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was put the preinit code in the code files of the other pages.